# Javascript object with function and this

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

I am learning Object of Javascript.
I have built some coding below. When I remove this.recall=recall, it did not work. But when I add this.recall=recall, The entire code worked. I do not know why I need to put this.recall=recall to get the result because it does not have any value when the function is recalled.

```js
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function recall (){
        document.write('the height is:'+ this.height+'<br>');
        document.write('the weight is:'+ this.weight+'<br>');
        document.write('the age is:'+ this.age+'<br>');
      }
      function Private(height,weight,age){
        this.height=height;
        this.weight=weight;
        this.age=age;
        this.recall=recall;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var man= new Private('170cm','60kg','26-year-old');
      man.recall();
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the constructor of your class:

```
      function Private(height,weight,age){
        this.height=height;
        this.weight=weight;
        this.age=age;
        this.recall=recall;
      }
```

You use this statement to add a method to the class:

```
this.recall=recall;
```

So you can call the function after you intialise an object of the class:

```
var man= new Private('170cm','60kg','26-year-old');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a function, it has to be in context of caller.
Here, new Private object is returned in reference variable man. now we can say that man is an object. if man object does not have recall method, it cannot call it.
Thus, while returning from the Private function, if recall function is part of object, it works.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wanna quickly ask what role the code 'this.recall=recall' has in function Private. Cuz it has some role since I removed it, it did not work.

Comment: you should read about new object in javascript.
when we call a function using new operator, it creates a new object.
everything which we assing using this.sth = sth. goes as properties of that object.

Comment: that new object is referenced by man variable.
so inside the recall function, this refers to man, since man called it.

Comment: Thank you Ronn, I sort of understood. I will read about New in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var man= new Private('170cm','60kg','26-year-old');
```

creats an object names Private which allows 3 fields :

```
 this.height
 this.weight
 this.age
```

AND a field that calls a function. It means that if you remove  `this.recall=recall;` then you cannot call `recall` from `man`